# C# get font from postscript name

Tags: c#, fonts, gdi+, gdi

I need to get the font (System.drawing.Font), with the given postscript name. For example, if I give the input as "CourierNewPSMT", the Courier font should be loaded.

Similarly if "Arial-Black" is the input, the "Arial Black" font should be loaded.

Any ideas??

Note : "Arial-Black" is the postscript name of "Arial Black" font.
       "CourierNewPSMT" is the postcript name of "Courier New" font.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
James

Comment: "Courier New" and "Arial Black" in Windows are TrueType fonts, not PostScript fonts. If you need to get PostScript equivalents, you'll need to map one set of names to the other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the postscript names of all the installed fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579593/find-the-postscript-names-of-all-the-installed-fonts)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, you can look at the font in Font Book and go under View › Show Font Info

You should see all the different naming conventions listed.